# Catch Exception from constructor without hiding the object in the try block

Tags: c++, exception

I have a class whose constructor might throw an exception.

```
class A {
    A() { /* throw exception under certain circumstances */ }
};
```

I would like to catch this exception in the client for a stack-allocated instance. But I find myself forced to extend the `try` block at least as far as the instance must be alive.

```
try {
    A a;
    do_something(a);
} catch {
    // ...
}
```

Now this obviously becomes a problem when the try block is too large to track down the source of the exception:

```
try {
    A a1;
    A a2;
    do_something(a1, a2);
} catch {
    // Who caused the exception?
}
```

What would I do to avoid the situation?

**UPDATE**:

It seems I hadn't explained the problem very well: For obvious reasons, I want to have the try block spanning as little code as necessary (that is, only the construction).

But that creates the problem that I can't use the objects afterwards because they have moved out of scope.

```
try {
    A a1;
} catch {
    // handle a1 constructor exception
}
try {
    A a2;
} catch {
    // handle a2 constructor exception
}

// not possible
do_something(a1, a2);
```

Comment: What's your use-case? How are you handling the exception?

Comment: Tag the allocated instances, and pass this tag with the exception.

Comment: Nothing really, unless you don't mind resorting to dynamic allocation. I'd ask why it really matters, though...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, I think it does matter how long your try block is. Having a 20-line try block where only 1 line can throw isn't exactly clean coding.

Comment: You can use a `unique_ptr` to control the object's lifetime instead of allocating the object on the stack, as @LightnessRacesinOrbit kind of suggested

Comment: @GManNickG: My usecase is exactly this: Constructing an object and using it afterwards. Not wanting to enclose everything in the try block.

Comment: @Andy Prowl: A `boost::optional` may make more sense, and will avoid the heap allocation.

Comment: This might not help you very much, but I have seen a lecture by Alexandrescu complaining about the fact that in C++ you can't implement something like on_error() in D, which would probably help achieving what you want

Comment: @JoSo: You're missing the point: [*why*](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)? If you want to catch the exception, you're going to have a try block. Anything else is just shuffling things around *and we can't help you do that if you don't tell us what you're doing in more detail*.

Comment: @GManNickG: I think what he would like to do is wrap with exception checking only the *construction* of `A`, not its whole lifetime. *And* he would like to allocate `A` on the stack. The nesting of long `try` blocks might be cumbersome to read. I think the question is legitimate. K-ballo provided an interesting solution IMO.

Comment: @GManNickG: I think you didn't get my point. I have updated the question.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Thx for the support, you got my point.

Comment: @Andy: But the whole point is that if construction of an object failed, then ALL the code that relies on that object having been constructed should sit within the block of code that will NOT continue to be executed. That's the whole point of try/catch being a block scoping mechanism. OP needs to explain concrete needs for abandoning C++'s very deliberate paradigms.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: well, that's the point of wrapping `A`'s construction within a `try-catch` block: detect if something is wrong with `A`'s construction and, if so, do cleanup and return. If A's construction succeeds, it might very well be the case that everything else after that is no-throw, and that could be done as well outside of the `try-catch` block.

Comment: @AndyProwl: If that stuff doesn't rely on A existing, arguably it could already be moved outside of the try-catch block. Maybe.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: i didn'y say `A`'s construction is no-throw, otherwise there would be no point wrapping it into a `try-catch` block. i assumed everything which is done *after* A's construction may be no-throw

Comment: All: (I hope I am not upsetting anybody by carrying on my reasonings. I somehow see I tend to get caught into long series of comments. If that disturbs you, please accept my apologies.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: that stuff does rely on `A` existing, but may consist for instance of a sequence of invocations of no-throw methods of `A`. It could be placed outside of the `try-catch` block, theoretically. As the OP says, the goal is to "have the try block spanning as little code as necessary", which is not a bad principle IMO

Comment: @AndyProwl: That just doesn't make sense. If the code were outside the block, what prevents you from reaching that code with no constructed `A`?

Comment: @Andy: I understand that those member functions couldn't throw but, on the other hand, if the object couldn't be constructed in the first place then you have nothing on which to invoke them.

Comment: @GManNickG: if an exception is thrown during `A`'s construction, the `catch` block handles it, does clean up, and returns. Of course, if you don't return nor set a flag saying that `A`'s construction failed and go on accessing `A`, you would get UB. That would just be a bug. The point here is: have the `try` block ("{...}") specify "exception-guarded zone" but not "lifetime scope" (just to point out, we're talking fantasy here, I know that can't be done in C++)

Comment: @AndyProwl: So the language should purposfully open a huge bug hole so that someone doesn't have to put some statements up a few lines to a try block? That's just silly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: if the object couldn't be constructed in the first place, you would not execute those lines that use it of course. you would just do cleanup and return in the `catch` clause

Comment: @GManNickG: no, it should not "purposfully open a huge bug hole so that someone doesn't have to put some statements up a few lines to a try block". but i feel it would be useless for me to try and formulate an answer, your approach to conversation seems destructive to me rather than constructive.

Comment: I think the suggested language feature is already perfectly solved by try-catch being a scope-aware feature.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Please consider this:

`unique_ptr<A> pA; try { pA.reset(new A); } catch (...) { // return if error } pA->do_something(); ... /* this may be very long */; `

Does the language allow you doing that? Yes. 

Is it a "purposefully open a huge bug hole so that someone doesn't have to put some statements up a few lines to a try block"? Don't think so.

What would it change if the language allowed doing the same by allocating `A` on the stack rather than dynamically? Nothing IMO.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: btw, just to get an idea of what I mean, see here: http://dlang.org/exception-safe.html. The D language was not designed by a "silly" guy, and it supports an additional, more elegant way of handling exceptions that C++ does not support. I hope C++ will borrow something like D's `scope(failure)` clause in future.

Comment: @Andy: That code would not pass review in my team. Now every time you use `pA` you need to check it for validity. Using try/catch properly you already had the ability before to know that the object existed wherever you tried to use it, at compile-time, because it had block scope, but you deliberately eschewed that safety and now must litter `if` statements about the place. It's a backward step.

Comment: Anyway, if the code is "very" long then you haven't separated it into functions properly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: OK, thank you for sharing your viewpoint in a constructive way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution that doesn't require changing `A` is to use nested try/catch blocks:

```
try {
    A a1;
    try {
        A a2;
        do_something(a1, a2);
    }
    catch {
      // a2 (or do_something) threw
    }
} catch {
    // a1 threw
}
```

Probably better to avoid doing this if possible though.

Comment: Won't use in practice. Very creative though.

Comment: @JoSo: This is the only way guaranteed to work for any type. If you use an [`expected<T>` utility](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C), you can make a `expected<T> try_construct<T>(Args...)` function that catches any exceptions thrown from construction and packs them into the `expected<T>`. The problem is that this requires your type have non-throwing copy (or ideally/more likely, move) constructors to safely get the `expected<T>` to the caller without throwing. That's probably your next best thing.

Comment: @GManNickG or Remy's idea with `boost::optional`

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yeah, that's pretty much what `expected<T>` would be, but without the exception info (or passed back a different way). Note it suffers the same problem: if I *do* hold an `A` in the optional, moving it out safely (without dynamic allocation, of course) requires `A`'s can be moved without throwing.

Answer (score 4):

Use heap-constructed objects instead of stack-constructed objects, so that you can test which objects have been constructed successfully, eg:

```
// or std::unique_ptr in C++11, or boost::unique_ptr ...
std::auto_ptr<A> a1_ptr;
std::auto_ptr<A> a2_ptr;

A *a1 = NULL;
A *a2 = NULL;

try
{
    a1 = new A;
    a1_ptr.reset(a1);
}
catch (...)
{
}

try
{
    a2 = new A;
    a2_ptr.reset(a2);
}
catch (...)
{
}

if( (a1) && (a2) )
    do_something(*a1, *a2);
```

Alternatively (only if `A` is copy-constructible):

```
boost::optional<A> a1;
boost::optional<A> a2;

try
{
    a1 = boost::in_place<A>();
    a2 = boost::in_place<A>();
}
catch (...)
{
    //...
}

if( (a1) && (a2) )
    do_something(*a1, *a2);
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `boost::optional`, but I very much dislike this code.

Comment: Note that C++11 *is* just "C++" now, so you should just use `unique_ptr` by default.

Comment: @GManNickG: unless you are not using a C++11 compiler yet, that is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Nope, C++ *is* C++11. If you're not using a C++11 compiler, you're using a legacy C++ language, not the current C++ language.

Comment: I feel this is the spirit of your answer, so isn't a competing idea necessarily.  But I think this is much cleaner and faster.  http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cad3ac736361a1ac7f420a206bfac848

Comment: @MooingDuck: That should be an answer. :)

Comment: @GManNickG: I understand that C++11 is the current C++ standard. That does not mean that every C++ compiler vendor has released an new C++11-compatible compiler yet.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Never said that was the case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Check again, with `boost::optional`, `a1 = A();` would be copy constructor.  `a1 = boost::in_place<A>();` uses the _default_ constructor!

Comment: Now you need those if statements, creating a new block. You've gained _nothing_. And should have just used the existing `try` block in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that might be convenient in some circumstances:

```
class ExceptionTranslatedA : public A {
public:
    template<typename Exc>
    ExceptionTranslatedA(Exc exc)
    try : A() {}
    catch (unhelpful_generic_exception) {
        throw exc;
    }
};
```

This is especially useful if throwing a different exception is all that you wanted to do in your original try-catch block, since you can get rid of it entirely. It also feels somewhat more elegant than introducing boolean variables for control flow (even if they're hidden in `boost::optional`s).